# TypeScript AMD in WebStorm. Annoying "Assigned Expression type" error

Tags: typescript, amd, webstorm

I'm trying out TypeScript in JetBrains WebStorm.

I have a very simple class in "person.ts":

```
export class Person {
  constructor(public name:string, public age:number) {
  }
    toString() {
    return this.name + ", " + this.age;
  }
}
```

Then, on my app.ts I try to import it like this:

```
import nsp = module("person");

export class App {
    start() {
        var my_user:nsp.Person;
        my_user = new nsp.Person("Julian", 111);
        console.log( my_user.toString() );
    }
}
```

This seems to work. I can use **tsc** to compile to javascript:

```
tsc --module AMD .\public\script\app.ts
```

And I've also set up a FileWatcher for TypeScript in WebStorm. It's fine.

But I'm getting this annoying error/warning: **"Assigned Expression type Person is not assignable to type exports.Person"**

[image: problem]

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in WebStorm?

Here's my project on GitHub: https://github.com/JulianG/typescript-modularization-demo/ in case you want to try it out.

Comment: Hello! This bug is already fixed, fix will be available in WebStorm 7

Comment: @lena a link to version 7? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! Wait... 7!? Do you know when will it be released?

Comment: Currently planned for September... But the EAP program will definitely start sooner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug is fixed in the next WebStorm release but in the meantime you could either ignore the error or combine the expression into a single line and see if type-inference helps:

```
var my_user = new nsp.Person('Julian', 111);
```

Comment: Thank you!! Actually it's the typing that's causing the problem.
I can keep it in 2 lines as long as I don't specify the type of my_user. like this: 
var my_user;
my_user = new nsp.Person("Julian", 111);

Comment: The problem happens when I specify the type.
var my_user:nsp.Person

Comment: @JulianG the slight issue with having it on two lines without the typing is the variable will be typed to `any` - using a single line with no typing, TypeScript should infer the type of `nsp.Person` so you still get static typing.

Answer (score 1):

Fix will be included in the next minor release also (6.0.2). Probably this was caused by [WEB-7117](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7117).

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings: Search for "type mismatch" and you will see the inspections where you can disable them.